# How to simulate click on the second element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, dom, click

I'm very new on web developing.
I want to ask on how Can I automatically
Click the second href, that contains the word "login"

This is the code that I tried

`document.querySelector('a[href*="/a/login.php?"]')[2].click();`

Answer (score 0):

You need `querySelectorAll for this` and since it's an array-like collection it starts with a zero index, which means you need to take `[1]` instead of `[2]`

`document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="/a/login.php?"]')[1].click();`

Answer (score 0):

function querySelector() returning only 1st element. You need to use .querySelectorAll() instead

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.container a');
links[1].click()
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="#">link1</a>
    <a href="#">link2</a>
  </div>
```